# Windows, FindResource error 1814

Tags: windows, binary, 64-bit, nmake

I have a problem embedding custom binary data into a Windows executable. The problem might also be with linking the resource or retrieving it, I don't know. Anyway the **FindResource returns NULL and error code is 1814**.

All the examples I've found include using an IDE of some sort or another, for creating the resource and building/making the executable. I need it to be done **automatically** by calling **nmake** on the **makefile**.

I'm doing it on **64bit Windows 7** using personal edition of **MS Visual Studio / C++** installed in default directories(s).

Here's the setup I put together (all the files in the same directory; nmake also called from this directory):

1. File: *custom.data.txt* with the follofing contents:

   ```
   My own personal custom data.
   ```

   Note that I'm only using text resource for this example. In reality I'll be using custom data in no particular format.
2. File: *custom.h* with the following contents:

   ```
   #define IDR_RCDATA1 101
   ```
3. File: *custom.rc* with the following contents:

   ```
   IDR_RCDATA1 RCDATA "custom.data.txt"
   ```

   Edit: if **#include "custom.h" is added to *custom.rc***, the example works as expected:

   ```
   #include "custom.h"
   IDR_RCDATA1 RCDATA "custom.data.txt"
   ```
4. File: *example.cpp* with the following contents:

   ```
   #include "custom.h"
   #include <windows.h>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

       HRSRC myResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_RCDATA1), RT_RCDATA);

       if(myResource == NULL) {
           DWORD WINAPI errorCode = GetLastError();
           cout << "Could not find resource! Error code: " << errorCode << "." << endl;
           return 0;
       }

       unsigned int myResourceSize = SizeofResource(NULL, myResource);
       cout << "Resource size: " << myResourceSize << endl;

       if(myResourceSize > 0) {

           HGLOBAL myResourceData = LoadResource(NULL, myResource);
           void* pMyBinaryData = LockResource(myResourceData);

           std::ofstream f("C:\\Users\\draver\\win_custom_resource\\extracted_resource.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
           f.write((char*)pMyBinaryData, myResourceSize);
           f.close();

           BOOL bResult = UnlockResource(myResource);
           bResult = FreeResource(myResource);
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```
5. File *makefile* with the following contents:

   ```
   NAME = example

   CC = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe"
   RC = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\RC.exe"
   RESOURCE_NAME = custom

   all : link

   link : compile
       $(CC) $(NAME).obj $(RESOURCE_NAME).res

   compile : resource
       $(CC) -c $(NAME).cpp /EHsc

   resource :
       $(RC) $(RESOURCE_NAME).rc

   clean :
       del *.obj
       del *.exe
       del *.res
       del extracted_resource.txt
   ```
6. File *setup.bat* that I'm calling before nmaking, with the following contents:

   ```
   call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64
   ```

---

The produced executable (example.exe) contains the "My own personal custom data." string (verified via a dump) as expected, but fails to retrive it when run.

The output is

```
    Could not find resource! Error code: 1814.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit: see the edit above (3. File: *custom.rc*) which solves the problem.**

Comment: Did you `#include "custom.h"` in your `custom.rc` file?

Comment: No, I didn't. In all the examples I found, the include wasn't there. Also, resource compiler didn't complain when producing .res file.

Comment: Well you need it because otherwise, it will not know that `IDR_RCDATA1 is 101, and then `FindResource` will fail (as it did). What happens if you *do* `#include` it?

Comment: With included "custom.h" it works perfectly. Thanks a million, Roger!

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Roger Rowland wrote:

> Did you `#include "custom.h"` in your custom.rc file?
>
> Well you need it because otherwise, it will not know that `IDR_RCDATA1` is `101`, and then `FindResource` will fail (as it did). What happens if you do `#include` it?